# Angular $http.post returns 404 error

Tags: angularjs, http, 3d-secure

I am using angular JS to send some data to Payment Gateway.

Syntax for curl to send data as per documentation is:

```
curl https://www.mybank.co.uk/3dsecure
-H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
-X POST
-d 'TermUrl=https://www.yourmerchantsite.co.uk/3DSecureConfirmation&PaReq=value-of-oneTime3DsToken&MD=merchantdatavalue'
```

However when I am doing it in Angular :

```
 $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: 'url',
         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                               'Accept': 'text/html'
                               },
         data: $.param({TermUrl: obj.TermUrl ,Pareq:  obj.Pareq }),

   })
```

I am getting error

```
     Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"<html><head><title>400 Bad 
     Request</title></head><body><h1>Bad Request</h1></body>
           </html>","status":400,"config":
          {"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":
         [null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"payement gatway 
     url","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml"},"data":"TermUrl=url&Pare
    q=value"},"statusText":"Bad Request","xhrStatus":"complete"}
```

Kindly suggest how to proceed with this one ?

Comment: Do you really use `url: 'url'` or it's just for example ?

Comment: @Mojo Allmighty No I just added for reference I am using proper values for all the required attributes

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are experiencing a 400 Bad Request (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) and not a 404 Not Found.

It usually means that you are not sending the right data to the server and the API is expecting some specific parameters (from the body usually).

Check the API, look at every parameter required from it - their types and how they should be sent (body param? query string? etc...).

You can use your browser network tab or tools like Postman to see what you are actually sending to the server and if it matches what the server is expecting you to send.

Answer (score 0):

Check out 3D Secure's API reference, you should get back a detailed error code beside the http status code:
https://developer.paysafe.com/en/3d-secure/api/#/introduction/error-summary/common-errors

It should be easily debuggable.